# Problems on double tap in windows phone

Tags: button, windows-phone-7, double-click

I have found a strange tap issue in my app. I have 42 buttons arranged 6x7 in the form of a calendar. Every button has calls the same function OnDoubleTap which is the one of the events of a button.

The problem is, successive taps on two buttons is treated as a double tap on the second tapped button.

```
public void OnButtonDoubleTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
       // function
}
```

this function is associated with all the 42 buttons through the xaml code like this

```
<Button x:Name="b00" Content="" Height="60" Width="68" MinWidth="68" MinHeight="60" Click="OnClick" DoubleTap="OnButtonDoubleTap" Foreground="#FF171717" BorderThickness="0" Hold="OnButtonLongPress" Style="{StaticResource DateButtonTemplate}" FontFamily="{StaticResource CicleFina}" />
<Button x:Name="b01" Content="" Height="60" Canvas.Left="68" Width="68" MinWidth="68" MinHeight="60" Click="OnClick" DoubleTap="OnButtonDoubleTap" Hold="OnButtonLongPress" Foreground="#FF171717" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource DateButtonTemplate}" FontFamily="{StaticResource CicleFina}"/>
<Button x:Name="b02" Content="" Height="60" Canvas.Left="136" Width="68" MinWidth="68" MinHeight="60" Click="OnClick" DoubleTap="OnButtonDoubleTap" Hold="OnButtonLongPress" Foreground="#FF171717" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource DateButtonTemplate}" FontFamily="{StaticResource CicleFina}"/>
<Button x:Name="b03" Content="" Height="60" Canvas.Left="204" Width="68" MinWidth="68" MinHeight="60" Click="OnClick" DoubleTap="OnButtonDoubleTap" Hold="OnButtonLongPress" Foreground="#FF171717" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource DateButtonTemplate}" FontFamily="{StaticResource CicleFina}"/>
<Button x:Name="b04" Content="" Height="60" Canvas.Left="272" Width="68" MinWidth="68" MinHeight="60" Click="OnClick" DoubleTap="OnButtonDoubleTap" Hold="OnButtonLongPress" Foreground="#FF171717" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource DateButtonTemplate}" FontFamily="{StaticResource CicleFina}"/>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Alfah

Comment: I'm not sure if it's directly related to your issue but handling both the `Click` and `DoubleTap` events is a route whihc is likley to lead to issues as both will be fired when the user doubletaps

Comment: @Matt Any suggestion as to how I can prevent this. These 42 buttons are dates and the double tap opens up a page where we can add notes on the date. So two taps on different button opens a page to add notes on the 2nd tapped button/date which is not at all a desired behaviour.

Comment: handling both the single and the double tap (click is, as far as the user of a touch screen device is concerned, the same as tap) leads to confusion and is not discoverable. Users also don't expect a "button" to respond to single and double tap separately. Use a context menu to access secondary functionality. You shoudl also use the built in calendar as a reference for expected functionality as this is the behaviour users will expect of a calendar interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by capturing the first click and the second click.
Check the names of the sender and do the function only if both has the same.

The first click is captured on the OnClick function and the second at the OnDoubleTap function

```
public void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button nbut = sender as Button;
    m_captureFirstClick = nbut.Name;
}

public void OnButtonDoubleTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Button temp = sender as Button;
    if (temp.Name == m_captureFirstClick)
    {
        // do what you want to do
    }
}
```

Alfah